Can you daven in the same room as a sleeping person?
If two Jewish people are in the same room, can one daven in that room if the other is asleep in the same room? Is there anything that would prohibit one from davening in the same room as a sleeping person?

If your issue is about reciting prayers when seeing something immodest, only if the sleeping person is not dressed properly and exposed can it be problematic (see SA OC Siman 74 and biur halacha there). But other than that, no issue should exist. This is clear by the fact that the poskim only discuss erva situations and similar issues and not the mere fact of someone sleeping.
There can be an issue of gezel sheina if you daven loud and wake the person up.

What do you mean by "era situations" ? And I thought gezel sheina wasn't really an issur (see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36755/is-gezel-shainah-a-real-thing)
